# How can I modify sqlite db on iPhone via ssh?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ssh

When i ssh to my iphone, i cannot found sqlite in ssh, is it possible to use sqlite shell in ssh?

```
ssh root@my-iphone-ip
pwd
sqlite /some-sqlite-db

-sh: sqlite: command not found
oops
```

---

after apt-get update, then everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use some script like python to do that